# Abnormality of Subscript Operator In C++

Tags: c++

I recently stumbled upon the following observation.
when overloading the unary ++ operator in the operand is before or after the operator as shown Below.

```
 void operator++(int y)
{
    x++;
}
```

or

```
 void operator++()
    {
        x++;
    }
```

But When Overloading Subscript operator the operand is placed between the operator.Like

```
int &operator[](float i)
  {
      return x[int(i)];
  }
```

Please Help me reach a conclusion.

Comment: ...that's just the way the syntax is. `operator` followed by the "name" of the operator. What's there not to get?

Comment: A conclusion about what?

Comment: I think he's confused about the fact `x` is able to be incremented and indexed too. But indeed his question is not exactly clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
void operator++(int y)
```

is a convention used by the compiler to distinguish this *postfix*  operator from the *prefix* version

```
void operator++()
```

In this case, the `y` is just a dummy variable, you can just leave the name out and define the postfix as `void operator++(int)`

On the other hand

```
int &operator[](float i)
```

is a different operator, and the `float` here is used as a real parameter (there is no prefix/postfix `operator[]`).